# storing value Turbo C++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to get my program to store a value so that it can display that value whenever there is an error. Here is my program :

```
void function()
{
    float abc[2];
    int i = 0;
    if ( i/2 != 0 ) 
    { 
      i++; 
      abc[0] = 1; 
    }
    abc[1] = abc[0];
    cout << abc[1];
}
```

Practically, my program keeps calling this function until I exit it, so it will keep updating my program and show me `abc[1]`. What I want is when the condition of the `if` statement is not met, `abc[1]` will display the previously known value of itself. How do I do it?.

Comment: If you want a persistent array between different calls to your function , then you should use static array..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what result you are trying for, but you need to make abc and i static, thusly:

```
void function()
{
    static float abc[2];
    static int i = 0;
    if ( i/2 != 0 ) { i++; abc[0] = 1; }
    abc[1] = abc[0];
    cout<<abc[1];
}
```

This will allow them to retain their value between function calls.  Right now that function is pretty silly, but I don't know what to recommend because I don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Lol. I understand wat u mean, the program has no sense at all, I just randomly create it to mimic the situation i'm in cause my actual program is very long and messy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand what you are meaning but if you want to store the previous value for printing why not just have an `abcPrevious` variable? After each loop (at the end) update it with the new value.

```
void function()
{
    static float abcPrevious;
    static float abc[2];
    static int i = 0;
    if ( i/2 != 0 ) 
    { 
      i++; 
      abc[0] = 1; 
    }
    abcPrevious = abc[1];
    abc[1] = abc[0];
    cout << "abc[1] is: " << abc[1] << "\nabcPrevious is: " << abcPrevious << endl;
}
```

Hopefully this helps :D